# Reference books that treat retirement savings/pension systems

Tags: saving, long-run, optimal-taxation, pensions

I'm looking for references (preferably, although not limited to, books) that treat the topic of pension/retirement savings systems academically, in particular I'm interested in getting introduced to questions like 'what is an optimal pension system' or 'conditional on the underlying aspects of an economy what types of pension systems are optimal'.

Hoping I'm not being too vague. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look for some introductory treatment you can have look at Baar  The Economics of the Welfare State Ch 7.

However, you should also read some of the preceding chapters to get full context. What is optimal does not depend only on type of economy but also on peoples preferences. For example, if people want something like pay as you go scheme, regardless of its sustainability, then it may be optimal purely because people find it pleasing. Ultimately what is optimal depends on the social welfare function as much as on parameters the economy has.